# Reset viewport rotation after leaving camera

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

Before entering Camera View, my Viewport looks like this
[image]

then, after leaving, the Viewport retains whatever rotation the Camera View had
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to disable this so that the Viewport doesn't retain the Camera View's rotation?

Comment: You might be able to use python for an automatic solution, but I usually just press a key on the numpad to align the view to one of the axes thereby resetting the tilt.